# Tried running a program and got this error

Tags: python, traceback

I was trying to follow along to a video ([This one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIXyj3WeyZM&list=PLsk-HSGFjnaGQq7ybM8Lgkh5EMxUWPm2i&index=12)) and i ran into a problem:

> "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a
> number, not 'NoneType'" (Full Traceback below)

It seems to be a problem with the pytmx code, but i cant decide whether i can fix it. could someone try to translate what this traceback means? thanks!

(I'm using Tiled, Python, Atom code editor, pygame, pytmx, and a windows laptop)

heres the code and the full traceback:

```
main.py:

# KidsCanCode - Game Development with Pygame video series
# Tile-based game - Part 12
# Loading Tiled Maps
# Video link: https://youtu.be/QIXyj3WeyZM
import pygame as pg
import sys
from os import path
from settings import *
from sprites import *
from tilemap import *

# HUD functions
def draw_player_health(surf, x, y, pct):
    if pct < 0:
        pct = 0
    BAR_LENGTH = 100
    BAR_HEIGHT = 20
    fill = pct * BAR_LENGTH
    outline_rect = pg.Rect(x, y, BAR_LENGTH, BAR_HEIGHT)
    fill_rect = pg.Rect(x, y, fill, BAR_HEIGHT)
    if pct > 0.6:
        col = GREEN
    elif pct > 0.3:
        col = YELLOW
    else:
        col = RED
    pg.draw.rect(surf, col, fill_rect)
    pg.draw.rect(surf, WHITE, outline_rect, 2)

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pg.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        pg.display.set_caption(TITLE)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.load_data()

    def load_data(self):
        game_folder = path.dirname(__file__)
        img_folder = path.join(game_folder, 'img')
        map_folder = path.join(game_folder, 'maps')
        self.map = TiledMap(path.join(map_folder, 'level1.tmx'))
        self.map_img = self.map.make_map()
        self.map_rect = self.map_img.get_rect()
        self.player_img = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, PLAYER_IMG)).convert_alpha()
        self.bullet_img = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, BULLET_IMG)).convert_alpha()
        self.mob_img = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, MOB_IMG)).convert_alpha()
        self.wall_img = pg.image.load(path.join(img_folder, WALL_IMG)).convert_alpha()
        self.wall_img = pg.transform.scale(self.wall_img, (TILESIZE, TILESIZE))

    def new(self):
        # initialize all variables and do all the setup for a new game
        self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.walls = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.mobs = pg.sprite.Group()
        self.bullets = pg.sprite.Group()
        # for row, tiles in enumerate(self.map.data):
        #     for col, tile in enumerate(tiles):
        #         if tile == '1':
        #             Wall(self, col, row)
        #         if tile == 'M':
        #             Mob(self, col, row)
        #         if tile == 'P':
        #             self.player = Player(self, col, row)
        self.player = Player(self, 5, 5)
        self.camera = Camera(self.map.width, self.map.height)

    def run(self):
        # game loop - set self.playing = False to end the game
        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.dt = self.clock.tick(FPS) / 1000.0  # fix for Python 2.x
            self.events()
            self.update()
            self.draw()

    def quit(self):
        pg.quit()
        sys.exit()

    def update(self):
        # update portion of the game loop
        self.all_sprites.update()
        self.camera.update(self.player)
        # mobs hit player
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.player, self.mobs, False, collide_hit_rect)
        for hit in hits:
            self.player.health -= MOB_DAMAGE
            hit.vel = vec(0, 0)
            if self.player.health <= 0:
                self.playing = False
        if hits:
            self.player.pos += vec(MOB_KNOCKBACK, 0).rotate(-hits[0].rot)
        # bullets hit mobs
        hits = pg.sprite.groupcollide(self.mobs, self.bullets, False, True)
        for hit in hits:
            hit.health -= BULLET_DAMAGE
            hit.vel = vec(0, 0)

    def draw_grid(self):
        for x in range(0, WIDTH, TILESIZE):
            pg.draw.line(self.screen, LIGHTGREY, (x, 0), (x, HEIGHT))
        for y in range(0, HEIGHT, TILESIZE):
            pg.draw.line(self.screen, LIGHTGREY, (0, y), (WIDTH, y))

    def draw(self):
        pg.display.set_caption("{:.2f}".format(self.clock.get_fps()))
        # self.screen.fill(BGCOLOR)
        self.screen.blit(self.map_img, self.camera.apply_rect(self.map_rect))
        # self.draw_grid()
        for sprite in self.all_sprites:
            if isinstance(sprite, Mob):
                sprite.draw_health()
            self.screen.blit(sprite.image, self.camera.apply(sprite))
        # pg.draw.rect(self.screen, WHITE, self.player.hit_rect, 2)
        # HUD functions
        draw_player_health(self.screen, 10, 10, self.player.health / PLAYER_HEALTH)
        pg.display.flip()

    def events(self):
        # catch all events here
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.quit()
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                    self.quit()

    def show_start_screen(self):
        pass

    def show_go_screen(self):
        pass

# create the game object
g = Game()
g.show_start_screen()
while True:
    g.new()
    g.run()
    g.show_go_screen()



sprites.py:

import pygame as pg
from random import uniform
from settings import *
from tilemap import collide_hit_rect
vec = pg.math.Vector2


def collide_with_walls(sprite, group, dir):
    if dir == 'x':
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(sprite, group, False, collide_hit_rect)
        if hits:
            if hits[0].rect.centerx > sprite.hit_rect.centerx:
                sprite.pos.x = hits[0].rect.left - sprite.hit_rect.width / 2
            if hits[0].rect.centerx < sprite.hit_rect.centerx:
                sprite.pos.x = hits[0].rect.right + sprite.hit_rect.width / 2
            sprite.vel.x = 0
            sprite.hit_rect.centerx = sprite.pos.x
    if dir == 'y':
        hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(sprite, group, False, collide_hit_rect)
        if hits:
            if hits[0].rect.centery > sprite.hit_rect.centery:
                sprite.pos.y = hits[0].rect.top - sprite.hit_rect.height / 2
            if hits[0].rect.centery < sprite.hit_rect.centery:
                sprite.pos.y = hits[0].rect.bottom + sprite.hit_rect.height / 2
            sprite.vel.y = 0
            sprite.hit_rect.centery = sprite.pos.y

class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image = game.player_img
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.hit_rect = PLAYER_HIT_RECT
        self.hit_rect.center = self.rect.center
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.pos = vec(x, y) * TILESIZE
        self.rot = 0
        self.last_shot = 0
        self.health = PLAYER_HEALTH

    def get_keys(self):
        self.rot_speed = 0
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_LEFT] or keys[pg.K_a]:
            self.rot_speed = PLAYER_ROT_SPEED
        if keys[pg.K_RIGHT] or keys[pg.K_d]:
            self.rot_speed = -PLAYER_ROT_SPEED
        if keys[pg.K_UP] or keys[pg.K_w]:
            self.vel = vec(PLAYER_SPEED, 0).rotate(-self.rot)
        if keys[pg.K_DOWN] or keys[pg.K_s]:
            self.vel = vec(-PLAYER_SPEED / 2, 0).rotate(-self.rot)
        if keys[pg.K_SPACE]:
            now = pg.time.get_ticks()
            if now - self.last_shot > BULLET_RATE:
                self.last_shot = now
                dir = vec(1, 0).rotate(-self.rot)
                pos = self.pos + BARREL_OFFSET.rotate(-self.rot)
                Bullet(self.game, pos, dir)
                self.vel = vec(-KICKBACK, 0).rotate(-self.rot)

    def update(self):
        self.get_keys()
        self.rot = (self.rot + self.rot_speed * self.game.dt) % 360
        self.image = pg.transform.rotate(self.game.player_img, self.rot)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = self.pos
        self.pos += self.vel * self.game.dt
        self.hit_rect.centerx = self.pos.x
        collide_with_walls(self, self.game.walls, 'x')
        self.hit_rect.centery = self.pos.y
        collide_with_walls(self, self.game.walls, 'y')
        self.rect.center = self.hit_rect.center

class Mob(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.mobs
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image = game.mob_img
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.hit_rect = MOB_HIT_RECT.copy()
        self.hit_rect.center = self.rect.center
        self.pos = vec(x, y) * TILESIZE
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.acc = vec(0, 0)
        self.rect.center = self.pos
        self.rot = 0
        self.health = MOB_HEALTH

    def update(self):
        self.rot = (self.game.player.pos - self.pos).angle_to(vec(1, 0))
        self.image = pg.transform.rotate(self.game.mob_img, self.rot)
        # self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = self.pos
        self.acc = vec(MOB_SPEED, 0).rotate(-self.rot)
        self.acc += self.vel * -1
        self.vel += self.acc * self.game.dt
        self.pos += self.vel * self.game.dt + 0.5 * self.acc * self.game.dt ** 2
        self.hit_rect.centerx = self.pos.x
        collide_with_walls(self, self.game.walls, 'x')
        self.hit_rect.centery = self.pos.y
        collide_with_walls(self, self.game.walls, 'y')
        self.rect.center = self.hit_rect.center
        if self.health <= 0:
            self.kill()

    def draw_health(self):
        if self.health > 60:
            col = GREEN
        elif self.health > 30:
            col = YELLOW
        else:
            col = RED
        width = int(self.rect.width * self.health / MOB_HEALTH)
        self.health_bar = pg.Rect(0, 0, width, 7)
        if self.health < MOB_HEALTH:
            pg.draw.rect(self.image, col, self.health_bar)

class Bullet(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, pos, dir):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.bullets
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image = game.bullet_img
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.pos = vec(pos)
        self.rect.center = pos
        spread = uniform(-GUN_SPREAD, GUN_SPREAD)
        self.vel = dir.rotate(spread) * BULLET_SPEED
        self.spawn_time = pg.time.get_ticks()

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.vel * self.game.dt
        self.rect.center = self.pos
        if pg.sprite.spritecollideany(self, self.game.walls):
            self.kill()
        if pg.time.get_ticks() - self.spawn_time > BULLET_LIFETIME:
            self.kill()

class Wall(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.walls
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image = game.wall_img
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect.x = x * TILESIZE
        self.rect.y = y * TILESIZE


tilemap.py:

import pygame as pg
import pytmx
from settings import *

def collide_hit_rect(one, two):
    return one.hit_rect.colliderect(two.rect)

class Map:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.data = []
        with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
            for line in f:
                self.data.append(line.strip())

        self.tilewidth = len(self.data[0])
        self.tileheight = len(self.data)
        self.width = self.tilewidth * TILESIZE
        self.height = self.tileheight * TILESIZE

class TiledMap:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        tm = pytmx.load_pygame(filename, pixelalpha=True)
        self.width = tm.width * tm.tilewidth
        self.height = tm.height * tm.tileheight
        self.tmxdata = tm

    def render(self, surface):
        ti = self.tmxdata.get_tile_image_by_gid
        for layer in self.tmxdata.visible_layers:
            if isinstance(layer, pytmx.TiledTileLayer):
                for x, y, gid, in layer:
                    tile = ti(gid)
                    if tile:
                        surface.blit(tile, (x * self.tmxdata.tilewidth,
                                            y * self.tmxdata.tileheight))

    def make_map(self):
        temp_surface = pg.Surface((self.width, self.height))
        self.render(temp_surface)
        return temp_surface

class Camera:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.camera = pg.Rect(0, 0, width, height)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def apply(self, entity):
        return entity.rect.move(self.camera.topleft)

    def apply_rect(self, rect):
        return rect.move(self.camera.topleft)

    def update(self, target):
        x = -target.rect.centerx + int(WIDTH / 2)
        y = -target.rect.centery + int(HEIGHT / 2)

        # limit scrolling to map size
        x = min(0, x)  # left
        y = min(0, y)  # top
        x = max(-(self.width - WIDTH), x)  # right
        y = max(-(self.height - HEIGHT), y)  # bottom
        self.camera = pg.Rect(x, y, self.width, self.height)


settings.py:

import pygame as pg
vec = pg.math.Vector2


# define some colors (R, G, B)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
DARKGREY = (40, 40, 40)
LIGHTGREY = (100, 100, 100)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
BROWN = (106, 55, 5)

# game settings
WIDTH = 1024   # 16 * 64 or 32 * 32 or 64 * 16
HEIGHT = 768  # 16 * 48 or 32 * 24 or 64 * 12
FPS = 60
TITLE = "Tilemap Demo"
BGCOLOR = BROWN

TILESIZE = 64
GRIDWIDTH = WIDTH / TILESIZE
GRIDHEIGHT = HEIGHT / TILESIZE

WALL_IMG = 'tileGreen_39.png'

# Player settings
PLAYER_HEALTH = 100
PLAYER_SPEED = 280
PLAYER_ROT_SPEED = 200
PLAYER_IMG = 'manBlue_gun.png'
PLAYER_HIT_RECT = pg.Rect(0, 0, 35, 35)
BARREL_OFFSET = vec(30, 10)

# Gun settings
BULLET_IMG = 'bullet.png'
BULLET_SPEED = 500
BULLET_LIFETIME = 1000
BULLET_RATE = 150
KICKBACK = 200
GUN_SPREAD = 5
BULLET_DAMAGE = 10

# Mob settings
MOB_IMG = 'zombie1_hold.png'
MOB_SPEED = 150
MOB_HIT_RECT = pg.Rect(0, 0, 30, 30)
MOB_HEALTH = 100
MOB_DAMAGE = 10
MOB_KNOCKBACK = 20
```

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wscur\Creative Cloud Files\Creative things (coding)\Tile Game\main.py", line 137, in <module>
    g = Game()
  File "C:\Users\wscur\Creative Cloud Files\Creative things (coding)\Tile Game\main.py", line 37, in __init__
    self.load_data()
  File "C:\Users\wscur\Creative Cloud Files\Creative things (coding)\Tile Game\main.py", line 43, in load_data
    self.map = TiledMap(path.join(map_folder, 'level1.tmx'))
  File "C:\Users\wscur\Creative Cloud Files\Creative things (coding)\Tile Game\tilemap.py", line 22, in __init__
    tm = pytmx.load_pygame(filename, pixelalpha=True)
  File "C:\Users\wscur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytmx\util_pygame.py", line 141, in load_pygame
    return pytmx.TiledMap(filename, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wscur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytmx\pytmx.py", line 360, in __init__
    self.parse_xml(ElementTree.parse(self.filename).getroot())
  File "C:\Users\wscur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytmx\pytmx.py", line 391, in parse_xml
    self.add_layer(TiledTileLayer(self, subnode))
  File "C:\Users\wscur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytmx\pytmx.py", line 962, in __init__
    self.parse_xml(node)
  File "C:\Users\wscur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytmx\pytmx.py", line 1072, in parse_xml
    self.data[y][x] = reg(*decode_gid(next(next_gid)))
  File "C:\Users\wscur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pytmx\pytmx.py", line 1052, in get_children
    yield int(child.get('gid'))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Can you provide the code that you tried to run also..? You can't expect us to watch that 20 minutes long video and find the code you ran and provide the answer.

Comment: error shows you in which like you have problem. Errors means that it tries to do `int(None)` and it can means you have `None` in some variable. And first you could/should use `print()` to see values in variables. It is called "print debuging".

Comment: BTW: I see you load some map - maybe this map has wrong data and it has problem to read it. You could test it with different map

Answer (score 0):

This error signify that you are trying to transform a `None` object to `int` with the method `int()` that can't takes `None` objects as parameter.

Since the error occurs here:

```py
yield int(child.get('gid'))
```

It signifies that `child.get('gid')` returns `None`.

You can avoid this error by adding a None-check or with a try-except that excepts your `TypeError`.